# ObjC multicast delegate with message forwarding—what happens to the returned value?

Tags: objective-c

I have created a multicast delegate in Objective-C which intercepts a message and then forwards it to multiple children by iterating through a list of children in `forwardInvocation`.  There's quite a bit more complexity but I don't think it's relevant to the question/problem.

```
- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation
{
    for (id child in self.children)
    {
        if ([child respondsToSelector:[anInvocation selector]])
        {
            [anInvocation invokeWithTarget:child];
        }
    }
}
```

This makes total sense for protocols which have `void` return type but what happens if they return a value?

I saw this problem coming and wrote the following unit test, which passes:

```
static NSUInteger _callCounter = 0;

@protocol TestProtocol <NSObject>
- (NSUInteger)requiredMethod;
@end


@interface TestClass : NSObject <TestProtocol>
@end

@implementation TestClass

- (NSUInteger)requiredMethod
{
    return ++_callCounter;
}

@end
```

␠

```
- (void)testCallerOrder
{
    _callCounter = 0;
    ProtococolMulticaster *multicaster = [[ProtococolMulticaster alloc] initWithProtocol:@protocol(TestProtocol)];

    //As the multicaster holds weak references, we need to retain the children
    NS_VALID_UNTIL_END_OF_SCOPE NSMutableArray *childReferences = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        id child = [TestClass new];
        [childReferences addObject:child];

        [multicaster addChild:child];
    }

    XCTAssertEqual([(id<TestProtocol>)multicaster requiredMethod], 3);
}
```

The expectation here is that the 3 children are all called and my static is incremented 3 times and then returned to me by the last child in the array.  Because this passed, my conclusion was that it is the last forwardInvocation to be called which gives the return value from `[(id<TestProtocol>)multicaster requiredMethod]`.

Is this assumption correct?  Can anyone explain exactly what is happening here?  Are there any edge cases that I may have missed which might make this unpredictable?

Comment: Edge case: there are no children or no child responds to the selector; then no invocation is done at all.

Comment: Well spotted.  My implementation appears to fall over by returning nil from `methodSignatureForSelector:` in this case.  I'll have to think about changing the design to protect against this.